# On the Tikz Math Library: Fibonacci sequence

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

On page 704/1318 Tikz manual there is an example to create Fibonacci sequence. I try to repeat as below:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {math}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzmath{
% Adapted from 
http://www.cs.northwestern.edu/academics/courses/110/html/fib_rec.html
function fibonacci(\n) {
if \n == 0 then {
return 0;
} else {
return fibonacci2(\n, 0, 1);
};
};
function fibonacci2(\n, \p, \q) {
if \n == 1 then {
return \q;
} else {
return fibonacci2(\n-1, \q, \p+\q);
};
};
int \f, \i;
for \i in {0,1,...,20}{
\f = fibonacci(\i);
print {\f, };
};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But got a blank page.

Do you know how to fix this please?

Comment: Try without the tikzpicture environment.

Comment: @ Torbjørn T., Thanks!! do you know why we do not need the tikzpicture environment, in this especial example?

Comment: You're not making a diagram, just printing text to the page. Any normal text you write inside a `tikzpicture` is ignored (kind of).

Comment: @ Torbjørn T., Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not making a diagram in this case, just printing text to the page, so you shouldn't have a `tikzpicture` environment. Normal text in a `tikzpicture` is not printed.

Note that there is no `tikzpicture` in that example in the manual either, but those examples where a diagram is drawn do have the `tikzpicture`.